# How to render a specific number of elements in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, babeljs, jsx

I'm trying to figure out how to display a specific number of these elements created with the functions in my code below. I've researched this an have seen that most people are using an array but I've not been able to make that work, perhaps because of some way my jsx is formatted.

```
import React from 'react';
import { videos } from '../../data/videos.json';
import styles from './covers.module.sass';

export const Covers = () => (
  <div>
    {videos.map((data, key) => {
        return (
            <Cover 
              key={key}
              cover={data.cover}
              title={data.title}
              subtitle={data.subtitle}
              description={data.description}
            />
        );
      })}
  </div>
);

const Cover = ({title, subtitle, description, cover}) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.coverContainer}>
      <img src={cover} alt={title + "cover image"} className={styles.coverImage} />
      <div className={styles.coverWordsContainer}>
        <h1 className={styles.coverTitle}>{title}</h1>
        <h2 className={styles.coverSubtitle}>{subtitle}</h2>
        <p className={styles.coverDescription}>{description}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Covers;
```

Comment: A specific number of what? Please clarify what you want to render a specific number of. If you want to render a specific number of `Cover` components then it seems the length of the `videos` array is the deciding factor for that.

Comment: Please provide the content of the video file

Comment: Hi, there are 5 videos in the array. I would like 14 videos to display on the page. So some will definitely be repeated.

Comment: Do you have a backend server serving the data for the videos? If you want data to be repeated the best way is to populate them that way. Also, please clarify what exactly is it that you want, and what you're stuck on :)

Comment: So some may repeat? Please share how, from an N length array of elements, you wish to render a length 14 array of UI elements.

Comment: Your JSX looks fine, but without knowing the results of videos or the error that you are receiving it will be hard to troubleshoot your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments I have read, it seems as though you want to create some duplicate elements if your array does not meet your desired length.

I would suggest using a function like:

```js
function fillArray(arr, desiredLen) {
  if (arr.length === desiredLen) {
    return arr;
  } else if (arr.length > desiredLen) {
    return arr.splice(0, desiredLen);
  } else {
    const iterations = Math.round(desiredLen / arr.length);
    let newArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
      newArr = newArr.concat(arr);
    }
    return newArr.splice(0, desiredLen);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to show the `videos` data to us。

```
import { videos } from '../../data/videos.json'
```

The videos data format may be have some error。